# How to create instance of JavaFx application and push there own parameters?

Tags: java, google-maps, javafx, google-maps-markers

I am trying to create map using Google Maps Api + JavaFx. In main class I read JSON file then create clusters and the point of programm is to show these clusters as markers with number of locations in it. 
So in main class I read JSON file then create `DBSCANClusterer clusterer = new DBSCANClusterer(coordinates, 2, 2);` and I have to push this into the class `GoogleMap`, where the JavaFX is creating `webView` and so on. Also I use this to use java code in script in my html file:

```
JSObject jsobj = (JSObject) webView.getEngine()
             .executeScript("window");
     jsobj.setMember("BrowserJavaObject", new BrowserJavaObject(clusterer));
```

Then the same thing have to be pushed further in `BrowserJavaObject` class, where all clustering calculations are. 
I tried to create object of `GoogleMap` class, but that doesn't work.
So how to make it work? Or does that even possible? Thank you for advice.

**JSONMain class:**

```java
public class JsonMain {

     static List<Coordinate> coordinates = new ArrayList<>();

    private static final String ITEMS_NAME = "items";
    private static final String LATITUDE_PROPERTY = "latitude";
    private static final String LONGITUDE_PROPERTY = "longitude";
    private static final String CRASH_NAME = "em_type_name";

    static void parseCrashCoordinates(final JsonReader jsonReader, final ICoordinatesListener listener)
            throws IOException {    
        // Reading JSON file
    }

     // Collecting all coordinates in ArrayList.
    private static void testCollecting()
            throws IOException {
      //  List<Coordinate> coordinates = new ArrayList<>();
        readAndParse((lat, lng) -> coordinates.add(new Coordinate(lat, lng)));
        System.out.println(coordinates.size());   
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        testCollecting();  


     // Initialize our clustering class with locations, minimum points in cluster and max Distance
        DBSCANClusterer clusterer = new DBSCANClusterer(coordinates, 2, 2);

        GoogleMap gm = new GoogleMap(clusterer);
        gm.launch(GoogleMap.class);
    }
```

**GoogleMap class:**

```java
public class GoogleMap extends Application {

private DBSCANClusterer clusterer ;

public GoogleMap(DBSCANClusterer c) {
    this.clusterer = c;
}


@Override 
public void start(Stage stage) throws MalformedURLException {

    File file = new File("C:/Users/Evgeny/git/Diploma_MSU/diploma/html/map.html");
    URL url222 = file.toURI().toURL();

     WebView webView = new WebView();
     final WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();

     JSObject jsobj = (JSObject) webView.getEngine()
             .executeScript("window");
     jsobj.setMember("BrowserJavaObject", new BrowserJavaObject(clusterer));

    webEngine.load(url222.toString()); 

    // create scene
    stage.setTitle("Web Map");
    Scene scene = new Scene(webView,1000,700, Color.web("#666970"));
    stage.setScene(scene);
    // show stage
    stage.show();

} 
}
```

**BrowserJavaObject class:**

```
public class BrowserJavaObject {

private DBSCANClusterer clusterer ;

public BrowserJavaObject(DBSCANClusterer c) {
    this.clusterer = c;
}

public String showMarkers() {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Coordinate>> clusters_raw= this.clusterer.performClustering();
    ArrayList<Cluster> clusters = new ArrayList<>();

    String pointsArray = " [ ";
    for(int i=0; i<clusters_raw.size(); i++) {
            Cluster c = new Cluster(clusters_raw.get(i));
            clusters.add(c);

            pointsArray += c.getLocationAsArray() + " , ";
    }
    pointsArray += "]";

    System.out.println("Number Of Clusters Created: "+clusters.size());
    return pointsArray;

}
}
```

**map.html:**

```HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Map</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
        html { height: 100% }
        body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
        #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script async defer type="text/javascript"
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=loadmap">
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="loadmap()">
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
<script>
var map;
function loadmap(){

  var options = {
      zoom: 16,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.7558, 37.6173),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), options);

  var markers = [];

  // Call the Java code to calculate clusters data, and save the returned clusters into a variable
  var markers_data = BrowserJavaObject.showMarkers();

  for( var i=0; i<markers_data.length; i++ ){
    var position = markers_data[i];
    var icon = "data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%2238%22%20height%3D%2238%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2038%2038%22%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23a22%22%20stroke%3D%22%23ccc%22%20stroke-width%3D%22.5%22%20d%3D%22M34.305%2016.234c0%208.83-15.148%2019.158-15.148%2019.158S3.507%2025.065%203.507%2016.1c0-8.505%206.894-14.304%2015.4-14.304%208.504%200%2015.398%205.933%2015.398%2014.438z%22%2F%3E%3Ctext%20transform%3D%22translate%2819%2018.5%29%22%20fill%3D%22%23fff%22%20style%3D%22font-family%3A%20Arial%2C%20sans-serif%3Bfont-weight%3Abold%3Btext-align%3Acenter%3B%22%20font-size%3D%2212%22%20text-anchor%3D%22middle%22%3E" 
                + position[2]
              + "%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E";

//    if(zoom > 11) icon = null; //Default to marker with no number if at city zom level

    markers.push( new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng( position[0], position[1] ),
                    map: map,
                    title: position[2],
                    text: position[2],
                    icon: icon
                }) 
    );
  } 
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So the map is loaded but no clusters there. And eventually that all these clustering methods are not invoked, because my `clusterer` object didn't passed further in other classes.

Thank you very much!

Comment: This is way too long. Consider posting [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `Application` class the wrong way. The `Application` class represents your entire application and is responsible for its lifecycle; in particular it has a `start()` method that is invoked for you when the JavaFX toolkit is started up by a call to `launch()`. The `Application` class doesn't represent a particular part of your UI (which is what your `GoogleMap` class appears to be for).

So you should make `JsonMain` a subclass of `Application`, not `GoogleMap`, and you should move the startup code to the (aptly-named) `start()` method:

```
public class GoogleMap {

    private DBSCANClusterer clusterer ;

    private final WebView view ;

    public GoogleMap(DBSCANClusterer c) throws MalformedURLException {
        this.clusterer = c;

        File file = new File("C:/Users/Evgeny/git/Diploma_MSU/diploma/html/map.html");
        URL url222 = file.toURI().toURL();

        view = new WebView();
        final WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();

        JSObject jsobj = (JSObject) webView.getEngine()
                 .executeScript("window");
        jsobj.setMember("BrowserJavaObject", new BrowserJavaObject(clusterer));

        webEngine.load(url222.toString()); 

    } 

    public Node getView() {
        return view ;
    }

}
```

and

```
public class JsonMain extends Application {

    static List<Coordinate> coordinates = new ArrayList<>();

    private static final String ITEMS_NAME = "items";
    private static final String LATITUDE_PROPERTY = "latitude";
    private static final String LONGITUDE_PROPERTY = "longitude";
    private static final String CRASH_NAME = "em_type_name";

    static void parseCrashCoordinates(final JsonReader jsonReader, final ICoordinatesListener listener)
            throws IOException {    
        // Reading JSON file
    }

     // Collecting all coordinates in ArrayList.
    private static void testCollecting()
            throws IOException {
      //  List<Coordinate> coordinates = new ArrayList<>();
        readAndParse((lat, lng) -> coordinates.add(new Coordinate(lat, lng)));
        System.out.println(coordinates.size());   
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)  
        throws IOException, URISyntaxException, MalformedURLException {

        testCollecting();  


     // Initialize our clustering class with locations, minimum points in cluster and max Distance
        DBSCANClusterer clusterer = new DBSCANClusterer(coordinates, 2, 2);

        GoogleMap gm = new GoogleMap(clusterer);

        // create scene
        stage.setTitle("Web Map");
        Scene scene = new Scene(gm.getView(), 1000, 700, Color.web("#666970"));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        // show stage
        stage.show();

    }

}
```

You should probably refactor further in order to properly separate your concerns; e.g. it's probably not the work of your `Application` class to be parsing data, etc. But this will at least let you pass parameters to your `GoogleMap` class and lets you start up the application in the intended way.